# PHP get file depending on anchor clicked

Tags: javascript, php, file

So I have multiple anchors that will get their id and text from a directory, these are ip addresses.

I can get the ip address from each when clicked into the title of a modal that the anchors open using this javascript in my php file:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
             document.getElementById("ipaddresstitle").innerHTML = this.id;
             var idoftitle = this.id
        });
</script>
```

But I want a file to be displayed in the div 'modal-body'. The file wants to be for example `/etc/ip_files/192.168.0.1` if I click 192.168.0.1 button. There will be a file that corresponds to each anchor.

I used this php before:

```
nl2br( file_get_contents('/etc/ip_files/192.168.0.1') );
```

it works manually. How can I make the div display the different text file each time I click one?

Is there a way that Javascript can output the file for me? Instead of using php?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript?

Comment: I am meaning a file on the server not the client

Comment: But the javascript is being executed on the client.  Would you want any client having access to your server's file system?  I would hope not.

Comment: The only way here since you want to load dynamic data from the server without reloading the page each time is to send an AJAX request with Javascript (on the client side) to your PHP script on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to send the ip address to the server to read the and send back the contents

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
             document.getElementById("ipaddresstitle").innerHTML = this.id;
             var idoftitle = this.id;
             $('#modal-body').load('script.php?ip='+encodeURIComponent(idoftitle));
        });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$ip = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ip', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
if ($ip){
    echo nl2br( file_get_contents('/etc/ip_files/'.$ip) );
}
```

Comment: Is that php in a seperate script.php file?

Comment: It could be if you want, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: This is just giving my a blank modal, am i correct that #modal-body is the ID and not the CLASS?

Comment: `modal-body` is the id.